# Use same Microsoft.excel object library on different computers with different Office versions

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2013. I add a reference for Microsoft Excel 16 (having office 2016) and this worked properly for this project.
But when I use this project on another computer containing Office 2013 I get a missing reference.
Can I fix this problem without having to install the same version of office in different computers?

Comment: You could use late binding and drop the references

Comment: [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/). [Open XML SDK - GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK)

Comment: What does your application use the Microsoft.excel library for?

Comment: I use reference for excel library to export data to excel  and how to use late binding to add and drop reference automatically , does  open xml sdk export to excel

Comment: Lots of libraries support exporting data to Excel. The library you're using is for automating Excel. But your goal isn't to automate excel. Your goal is to create a file that Excel can open. You shouldn't need Excel itself for that. Check our libraries such as [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using Excel Interop without worrying about versioning, then you need a wrapper like [NetOffice](https://github.com/NetOfficeFw/NetOffice).  I have used this extensively with legacy code and can vouch that it solves these kinds of issues.

However, as @Jimi and @BenCamps allude to, if you can do what you need to without using interop, you should.  If you are just doing exports, dealing with OpenXML or a wrapper of it like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) (which is awesome) will have less overhead and be less fragile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit referencing libraries, you can dynamically create Excel application by using late binding. But you will loose the IntelliSense...

**C#**

```
dynamic xlApp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"));
var xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\mybook.xlsx");
var xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets[1];
// Other code...
```

**VB**

```
Dim xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\mybook.xlsx")
Dim xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
```